# Difference between B and b before 8-bit binary number

Tags: assembly, binary

I am looking at some MPASM firmware code where 8-bit binary numbers are being loaded into status registers at the beginning of the program to set up the processor.

```
#define DEF_INTCON  B'10100000'
#define DEF_OPTION  B'10000111'       
#define GPIO_TRIS   B'11010000'      
#define DEF_GPIO    B'00000000'       
#define DEF_ANSEL   B'01111000'        
#define AN0_ADCON0  b'00000001'       ; CHS<2:0> 000 above settings for AN0
#define AN1_ADCON0  b'00000101'       ; CHS<2:0> 001 above settings for AN1
#define AN3_ADCON0  b'00001101'       ; CHS<2:0> 011 above settings for AN3
#define DEF_ADCON0  AN3_ADCON0
```

What is the difference between the big B and the little b?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They're the same.  The radix types aren't case sensitive.

Comment: Thank you. I thought so and from other examples of code I couldn't see a difference but it always help to hear it from someone with a lot more knowledge.

Comment: No problem.  It's a bit confusing to mix & match in a given source file like your example.